# How to grab utm source data from Google analytics Receiver in android?

Tags: android

I want to grab the utm source from appstore url and save on my server but i am not able to get that. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android referral removed in analytics v3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20126584/android-referral-removed-in-analytics-v3)